# Why Laravel 5.0 on Openshift set to APP_DEBUG false, but the website still shows debug info?

Tags: php, laravel, openshift

I've changed rhc by simply running  rhc env-set APPLICATION_ENV="Production" followed by a rhc app restart -a . And the env is set as following now:

```
APPLICATION_ENV=Production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_ENV=Production
```

But the website still gives the detailed debug information? How can I correct it? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't do anything, but the problem is gone now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try stopping & starting your application and see if that helps.  Apache probably needs to be restarted to pick up the env variable change.

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't set `APP_DEBUG` directly. Both `APP_DEBUG` and `APP_ENV` are intended to be managed by changing OpenShift's `APPLICATION_ENV` environment variable.

Check out the instructions in the readme and on the OpenShift Developer Portal: https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel#development-mode

Comment: Developer Portal version: https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-framework-laravel.html#__development_mode

Answer (score 0):

As other(s) are saying - yes, do this
https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel#development-mode

*BUT* then you need to git PUSH so that OpenShift re-writes your laravel .env file on their side.